# Strange solution for differential equation $dy/dx = \cos^2{x}\cos{y}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is easily integrable however, to make $y$ the subject of the equation gets a strange result.

$$\sec{y} +\tan{y} = Ae^{1/2x+1/4 \sin{(2x)}}$$

The first way is by Weirstrauss substitution to combine the $\sec{y} + \tan{y}$

The second way is to form a quadratic in $\sin{y}$, which gives $$y=\arcsin\left(\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{4-4\left(1+A^{2}e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin2x+x\right)}\right)\left(1-A^{2}e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin2x+x\right)}\right)}}{2\left(1+A^{2}e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin2x+x\right)}\right)}\right)$$

Note the plus minus, HOWEVER, when put into desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aez6zkd92u) I see that this solution is only valid if the numerator is infact $$\pm(2-\sqrt{...})$$ specifically plus for $A<0$ and minus for $A>0$. Perhaps I have formed my quadratic equation incorrectly but I don't think so. The solution graph is in red but I don't know how this solution was attained. (Wierstrauss gives $2\arctan{(...)}$ due to $\tan{(\frac{y}{2})}$)

Why is this happening to my quadratic? Can you simply "factorize" out the $\pm$?

Comment: But naturally, $-(\pm) = \mp$.

Comment: I dont understand.

Comment: Oh wait, I made a mistake - I thought for a short moment that arcsin was even. I'm not quite sure either now.

Comment: How can I "bump" this question without reposting it?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\tan(y)+\sec(y)=\frac{2}{e^{iy}-i}-i=f(x)\implies e^{iy}=\frac{2}{f(x)+i}+i=-i\frac{i-f(x)}{i+f(x)}$$
$$\implies y=-i\log\Bigg(e^{-i\pi/2}\frac{i-f(x)}{i+f(x)}\Bigg)$$
This function is absolutely real, however it has discontinuous jumps as function of $f(x)$. Up to jumps
$$y=-2\arctan(f(x))-\pi/2+2\pi n, \quad n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Hi, I don't really get how this answers my question. Your last equation looks different to my and the answer's solution (see graphs on desmos)